# PowerPC MySql Connector/C compilation

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I am trying to cross compile MySql Connector/C for Linux/PowerPC.

I am using

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`pwd`/ppc \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="powerpc-e500v2-gcc" \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="powerpc-e500v2-g++" \
-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-lm"
```

to generate make file.

When i try to make mysql conector it return me this error:

`Linking CXX static library libmysys_ssl.a
[ 89%] Built target mysys_ssl
Scanning dependencies of target comp_err
[ 89%] Building C object extra/CMakeFiles/comp_err.dir/comp_err.c.o
Linking CXX executable comp_err
[ 89%] Built target comp_err
Scanning dependencies of target GenError
[ 89%] Generating ../include/mysqld_error.h, ../sql/share/english/errmsg.sys
./comp_err: 1: ./comp_err: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make[2]: *** [include/mysqld_error.h] Error 2
make[1]: *** [extra/CMakeFiles/GenError.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

any ideas what is the problem?